# How to Link Payments to Smart Meters Using Python GridDB Client and Implement Triggers?

Tags: python, database, triggers, griddb

I'm working on a project that involves managing payments and smart meters using the Python GridDB client. I've successfully set up a GridDB environment and populated a "Payments" container with payment data from a CSV file, as shown in the code snippet below:

```
import datetime
import griddb_python
import csv
import random
import time
griddb = griddb_python
factory = griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()

gridstore = factory.get_store(
    host="",
    port=,
    cluster_name="",
    username="",
    password=""
)

gridstore.drop_container("Payments")
expInfo = griddb.ExpirationInfo(1, griddb.TimeUnit.MINUTE, 5)

conInfo = griddb.ContainerInfo("Payments",
    [["timestamp", griddb.Type.TIMESTAMP],
    ["amount", griddb.Type.FLOAT],
    ["transaction_id", griddb.Type.STRING],
    ["payment_phone_number", griddb.Type.STRING]],
    griddb.ContainerType.TIME_SERIES, expiration=expInfo)

ts = gridstore.put_container(conInfo)

with open("payments.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(row["timestamp"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        amount = float(row["amount"])
        transaction_id = row["transaction_id"]
        payment_phone_number = row["payment_phone_number"]
        ts.put([timestamp, amount, transaction_id, payment_phone_number])
```

Now, I'm facing the following challenges:
**Link Payments to Smart Meters**: I have a separate container for smart meters, and I need to link payments to smart meters based on matching transaction IDs. For instance, if a payment has a matching transaction ID in the smart-meter container, I want to associate it with the corresponding smart meter. What's the most efficient way to achieve this linkage? I've written a function below but I am open to suggestions.

**Implement Triggers for Meter Sensors**: Once payments are linked to smart meters, I want to implement triggers for meter sensors. These triggers should perform certain actions based on payment events, such as updating meter readings or initiating token calculations. How can I set up these triggers effectively within the GridDB environment?

```
def link_payments_to_smartmeters(gridstore, payments_container, smartmeters_container): 

    # Get the payments data.
    payments_data = gridstore.query(payments_container, "select *")

    # Iterate over the payments data.
    for payment in payments_data:
        # Get the transaction_id.
        transaction_id = payment[1]

        # Get the smartmeter data for the transaction_id.
        smartmeters_data = gridstore.query(smartmeters_container, "select * where smartmeter_id = ?", transaction_id)

        # If the smartmeter data is not empty, then link the payment to the smartmeter.
        if smartmeters_data:
            smartmeter = smartmeters_data[0]
            gridstore.put(payments_container, [payment[0], payment[1], smartmeter[0], smartmeter[1]])
```